# Form1 is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, simple-injector

After many hours, I couldn't find a appropriate answer for my problem even I see  lots of problem like my problem in stackoverflow web site.
Before I explain the problem I would like to say I implemented simpleInjector for dependency injection in a windows form application and as you see in below picture 
[image]
**This error occurred :**

> The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>   -[Disposable Transient Component] Form1 is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.
>   See the Error property for detailed information about the warnings. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix problems and how to suppress individual warnings.

I implemented `SimpleInjector` Like an example in this website [Doing dependency injection in Windows Forms](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windowsformsintegration.html)

**codes :**

> Main form (Form1)

```
namespace WindowsFormsAppSqliteDapper
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        IStudentService _studentService;
        public Form1(IStudentService studentService)
        {
            _studentService = studentService;
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var res = _studentService.GetStudents();

        }
    }
}
```

> Simple Injector Configuration (Program.cs)

```
namespace WindowsFormsAppSqliteDapper
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static Container container;
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Bootstrap();
            Application.Run(container.GetInstance<Form1>());
        }
        private static void Bootstrap()
        {
            // Create the container as usual.
            container = new Container();
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle =  new  AsyncScopedLifestyle();

            // Register your types, for instance:
            container.Register<IStudentService, StudentService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            //container.Register<IUserContext, WinFormsUserContext>();
            container.Register<IStudentRepository, StudentRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register<Form1>();

            // Optionally verify the container.
            container.Verify();

        }
    }
}
```

**If something like packages or etc you need to see , I'll put here.
Thanks**

Comment: The Error message is clear: Transient stuff is not allowed to implement IDisposeable. Now the System.Windows.Forms.Form class inherits the implementation back from System.Windows.Forms.Control. So it implements the interface and thus is not allowed to be transient.

Comment: @Christopher how I can fix it? I don't know where should I changed.see this https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windowsformsintegration.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my Code in this line

```
container.Register<Form1>();
```

to

```
container.Register<Form1>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

and it works fine .You can see full code in below

```
 private static void Bootstrap()
        {
            // Create the container as usual.
            container = new Container();
           // container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle =  new  AsyncScopedLifestyle();

            // Register your types, for instance:
            container.Register<IStudentService, StudentService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
            //container.Register<IUserContext, WinFormsUserContext>();
            container.Register<IStudentRepository, StudentRepository>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
            container.Register<Form1>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

            // Optionally verify the container.
            container.Verify();

        }
```

Comment: This only works if you will only have 1 `Form1` ever (and the services are Singleton too). I think setting everything to Singleton kind of defeat the purpose of a DI.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/disposabletransientcomponent.html) on how to fix that, the severity is just Warning so you can safely ignore it:

> The warning can be suppressed on a per-registration basis as follows:
>
> ```
> Registration registration = container.GetRegistration(typeof(IService)).Registration;
>
> registration.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent,
>     "Reason of suppression");
> ```